# Python / Tkinter grid sticky not filling vertical space

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a grid of buttons. The text within these buttons will change, so I want to buttons to be large - filling the borders of each grid element. The code below is a simplified version which illustrates the issue. The buttons mostly fill the horizontal space, but do not fill the vertical space (unless multiple lines of text are added as a button label).

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
buttons = {}
for y in range(3):
    root.rowconfigure(y, minsize=60)
for x in range(3):
    root.columnconfigure(x, minsize=60)
    for y in range(3):
        n = 3 * x + y
        buttons[n] = Button(root).grid(column=x, row=y, sticky=W + E + N + S)
root.mainloop()
```

This is what this yields for me:

[image: tkinter sample window]

Comment: Strange, [works on my machine](http://i.imgur.com/WCltkkm.png). Maybe this is Mac-specific behavior?

Comment: I can replicate (on a Mac).

Comment: Incidentally, this is probably not the source of your problem, but your `buttons` dict will contain nothing but `None` values, because you're adding the results of `grid` rather than the Buttons themselves.

Comment: @Kevin: must be, because when I run this code on the stock 2.7 distribution with OS X I get the same result as the OP.

Comment: Instead of using math to compute the dict key, are you aware you could use a tuple like `buttons[(x,y)]`. Doing so may make your code a little easier to understand.

Answer (score 3):

Buttons on OSX really want to look like OSX buttons, and won't expand the way you want. This is one of the pitfalls of using native widgets.

Comment: Thanks! Wish I knew this before I spent all that time trying to figure out what I was doing wrong.