# get rid of blank space around widgets in tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I put widgets on a window with `.grid` and noticed that the widgets have space around them. I fixed that on canvas widget with `highlightthickness` but this doesn't work with button widgets. It doesn't look cool when you have grey window background and there's white space around buttons.
P.S. I use python3 on macos Sierra

```
root = Tk()
root.configure(bg='grey')

w = Canvas(root, width=150, height=150, highlightthickness=0)
w.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

clear_btn = Button(text="Clear", width=15, command=lambda: w.delete("all"))
clear_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```

P.S. [TKinter leaving borders around widgets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27084321/tkinter-leaving-borders-around-widgets) that's what it looks like. The guy was advised to use `highlightbackground`, but when I screenshot widgets, I still have that blank space around the widget.

Comment: Can we see your script?

Comment: please show a [mcve]. There are multiple causes of space around widgets. Without seeing your code it's impossible for us to offer a fix.

Answer (score 2):

To get the button to fill the entire space of the grid box it occupies, try setting the `sticky` argument of the `grid()` function to `"NSEW"`:

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.configure(bg = "grey")

w = Canvas(root, width = 150, height = 150, highlightthickness = 0)
w.grid(row = 1, column = 1, sticky = "NSEW")

clear_btn = Button(text = "Clear", width = 15, command = lambda: w.delete("all"))
clear_btn.grid(row = 2, column = 1, sticky  =  "NSEW")

root.mainloop()
```

**Before:**

[image: before]

**After:**

[image: after]

**Note:** The appearance of these windows may vary slightly between operating systems and even between different visual themes on the same operating system.

Comment: it looks completely different on mac. Your solution won't help me.  But thanks anyway))

Comment: @Igor234 I was worried about that. I noticed the same issue when teaching a Python workshop for making a basic calculator in tkinter: One of the participants was on macOS and tkinter couldn't interact with the buttons in the same way that it did on Windows 7 or Raspbian Linux. After a little digging, I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27566488/python-tkinter-grid-sticky-not-filling-vertical-space), where Brian Oakley answers "Buttons on OSX really want to look like OSX buttons, and won't expand the way you want. This is one of the pitfalls of using native widgets."

Comment: I added some more information to my question. Could you check?

Comment: @Igor234 I just checked. For the question you cited, did you look at the answer? Brian Oakley answered that same question and again pointed out the issues with OSX and its native widgets. Quoting him, "The best you can do is set `highlightbackground` to the same color as your background so that it blends in."

Comment: @Igor234 Ultimately, it looks like you may either need to either rework the problem so that it is more compatible with OSX native widgets, or use a GUI package other than tkinter that doesn't make use of native widgets, unless someone else more familiar with OSX has come up with a novel solution of which I am unaware, which is always a possibility.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have OSX, so I cannot check, but I think that if you use `ttk` and a style different from the default one (like 'clam'), you might be able to configure things like you want.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()
root.configure(bg='grey')

style = ttk.Style(root)
style.theme_use('clam')

w = tk.Canvas(root, width=150, height=150, highlightthickness=0)
w.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky="nsew")

clear_btn = ttk.Button(text="Clear", width=15, command=lambda: w.delete("all"))
clear_btn.grid(row=2, column=1)

root.mainloop()
```